# How to find org's date of creation?

Tags: email, governorlimits

I want to know if my org was created before Winter '12 so that the higher outbound email limit will apply. How do I find my org's date of creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the `Organization` object's `CreatedDate` field

```
Organization org = [SELECT CreatedDate FROM Organization];
System.debug(org.CreatedDate); //2012-11-30 17:05:02
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [Apex limits Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) ? I think the following apex should return what you're looking for:

```
Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations();
```